# Special characters are returned as part of download rest service in spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have spring based rest web service to download the document. I am facing the strange issue with this service. If i invoke this rest service directly from browser address bar, i am able to download the document with right characters. However if i call the same rest service from the rest client/angular application, i am getting some special characters and document is not in right format.

Below is the spring rest service code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadResume(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "id") String id)
        throws Exception {


    File file = new File("C:/resume.doc");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
    httpHeaders.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    httpHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "test");

    return new ResponseEntity(bytes, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Below are the request header parameters used while calling the download service from the rest client.

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101      Firefox/40.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:8080/dist/index.html
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1133600505.1423631305; _gat=1
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Update:**
Added the angular code below. But the same issue exists with the service call from rest client as well.

```
downloadFactory.download(id)
                .then(function(response) {
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'test';;
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

                }, function(error) {                        
                });
```

Comment: did you set character Encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: No, i have not set any character encoding explicitly.

Comment: I suppose it is an issue with client Angular application. you might paste angular code and angular tag to the post

Comment: @brainstorm Updated the question with the angular code. But i am facing the same issue even i invoke the service from advanced rest client. I guess i missed something about character encoding in request headers.